# directional key problem in tkinter(python)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
key=0
win=Tk()
def get_input(event):
    global key
    key = event.keysym
    if key == "Up":
        direction = 0
    if key == "Down":
        direction = 1
    if key == "Left":
        direction = 2
    if key == "Right":
        direction = 3
    print(direction)

win.bind("<Key>", get_input)

win.mainloop()


while(1):
    get_input(event)
```

I don't know what's wrong with this, but my computer is telling me that 'event' is not defined.

"NameError: name 'event' is not defined"

Can you please tell me what I should do to fix this code?

Comment: Why use a while loop

Answer (score 0):

I think this part will never go,why dont u delete it?

```
while(1):
    get_input(event)
```

Comment: This code can't get the directional keys as input. Can you tell me how to?

Answer (score -1):

The issue is at the bottom, when you call `get_input(event)`. Here, you're trying to call the function `get_input` and you're using the variable `event` as the argument. However, `event` has not been defined. `event` is also the name of the parameter to `get_input`, but the name `event` will be assigned to whatever you pass to the function `get_input`. This is an explanation of why your code doesn't work, see pepper's answer for a solution.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I'm new to python, so I can't really understand what you said about event not being defined. Can you please explain it one more time?

Comment: @김규민 In your program, the name `event` corresponds to two different things. Inside your function, `event` is a [local](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) variable whose value is whatever you pass to the function (`event` is a parameter of the function `get_input`). Inside your while loop, you attempt to call this function by passing a variable `event` to the function. However, since this call is outside of the function, the Python compiler assumes you're trying to use a _global_ variable called `event`, which doesn't exist because you've never defined that global variable.